# How do I get the "Click Share" of an Ad Group from the Google AdWords API?

Tags: google-ads-api

As you can see in my screenshot, the Google Ads interface for my account shows the "Clicks" and "Click Share" columns. Based on what Google stated any column that is in the Google Ads interface should also exist in the Google AdWords API's corresponding report.

As you will see in the link below, the Google AdWords API's "Ad Group Performance Report" does not offer the "Click Share". It is offered as "Search Click Share" in the Campaign Performance Report and Shopping Performance Reports. https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/adgroup-performance-report

Does anyone know how I can get the Ad Group Click Share, even if it is using some other fields to infer the value from?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Did you intend to show a screenshot in this, or were you referring to the documentation link you've added?